# Bamboo and Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, maven, webdriver, testng, bamboo

I've developed some testcases localy with this setup:
Eclipse,
Selenium webdriver 2.0,
Maven 2,
TestNG,
Git

When I run the test via Maven test it works just fine. But now my next task is to move My tests to Bamboo. I've searched at Atlassians HomePage but not found any good information on how to do it.

I figure I must install webdriver on the Bamboo server? And then?
Could someone please tell me how to set up Bamboo so IT would run My tests?

Best regards, P

Comment: I hope you didn't start with Maven 2, cause Maven 2 has reached it's [End of Life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html).

Comment: Sorry about that, my bad. I'm using version 3,02 (m2) in Eclipse.

Comment: Really? No one who knows?

Comment: did you check the atlassian forum? https://answers.atlassian.com/search/?t=question&q=selenium

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ruby Selenium, so my setup is going to be different. I'll explain it anyways, in case it helps you go find your solution.

My selenium tests are written using Ruby, wrapped in RSpec (test framework). The Rspec tests are called via Rake tasks (like ANT).

On the Bamboo side, each job looks like this:

1. Source code checkout
2. Bundle install (get GEMs & dependencies)
3. Rake task : Bamboo Rake task that runs the named Rake task (which results in RSpec-Selenium tests running)
4. JUnit Parser (rake is configured to output the results of RSpec in JUnit format using CI_Reporter) parses results of tests, so Bamboo knows what passed/failed. I have this in the job config -> tasks -> final tasks section in bamboo; anything in this section will run even if a previous task failed.